# Remove elements from array A if those elements are contained in arrays B0 ... Bn - using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a character array `char[] a_chA` that contains elements i don't want.

The elements i don't want are in some more character arrays in a list `List<char[]> l_a_chB`.

I would like to remove all the unwanted elements using linq, but i can't seem to get the syntax right!

Something like ...

```
char[] a_chResult = l_a_chB.All(chRemove => a_chA.Union(ch => ch != chRemove))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want help with? Do you have a specific issue? Stack Overflow is not a 'code for me service'.

Comment: @Delan Azabani, If i want help on how to appear presumptive and rude, i will let you know. On the other hand, if want some professional programming advice, i will address the remaining members of the forum.

Comment: There is no need for name-calling.

Answer (score 3):

```
var charsInAExceptInAllBs = a_chA.Where(a => !l_a_chB.SelectMany(x => x).Contains(a)).ToArray();
```

This takes the elements in the B lists, flattens them (that's the `SelectMany` call) and then filters the elements of A by those characters that apper in the newly flattened B lists (that's the `Where` call.)

Note that if you don't have any duplicates in A (or don't care about losing duplicates) then you can use this:

```
var charsInAExceptInAllBs = a_chA.Except(l_a_chB.SelectMany(x => x)).ToArray();
```

Because `Except` takes the *set* difference, it will eliminate duplicates in the final result.

Comment: Cheers, am giving it a shot now. Thanks for the extra info - i think i need to go back and relearn some of the basics!

Answer (score 1):

```
var chars = from c in l_a_chB
            from x in c
            select x;    
var result = a_chA.Except(chars);
```

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = a_chA.Except(l_a_chB.SelectMany(a=>a));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Think i have it nailed now.